# Using @CrossOrigin with old Annotations

Tags: java, spring, cors

I have upgraded my Spring version from 3.0.5 to 4.2.5. Can I use the `@CrossOrigin` annotation (new to Spring 4.2.5) with previously used annotations like `@POST`, `@Path`, `@Consumes`, and `@Produce`? Or, will I have to move my controller to newer annotations like `@RestController`, `@RequestMapping`, and `@ResponseBody`?

Comment: formatting and grammar

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing frameworks here.
Spring MVC already had `@RequestMapping`, `@ResponseBody`, etc back in version `3.0.5.RELEASE`. `@POST`, `@Path` are JAX-RS annotations. So yes, if you want to use MVC features such as `@CrossOrigin`, you should use Spring MVC.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong after so much research on this. I finally end up with using two dispatchers one for JAX-RS and one for Spring-MVC. Now I am using both type of controllers in my project.
Thanks for your help :)